# How to enable or disable a radio based on 2 other radio buttons using jquery?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have 3 radio buttons as

```
<div>
<input class="crm-form-radio" value type="radio" id="CIVICRM_QFID_is_recur_radio" name="is_recur_radio">
<label for="CIVICRM_QFID_is_recur_radio">Single</label>
</div>

<div>
<input class="crm-form-radio" value="month" type="radio" id="CIVICRM_QFID_month_is_recur_radio" name="is_recur_radio">
  <label for="CIVICRM_QFID_month_is_recur_radio">Month</label>
</div>

<div>
<input class="payment_processor_gocardless crm-form-radio" value="5" type="radio" id="CIVICRM_QFID_5_payment_processor_id" name="payment_processor_id" >
<label for="CIVICRM_QFID_5_payment_processor_id">Payment</label>

</div>
```

My desired result is, when I select **Single** the **Payment** radio should be disabled.

And when I select **Monthly** the **Payment** radio should be enabled

This is what I have tried and was able to successfully disabled the **payment** radio, but cant enable it when select **Monthly**. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
$('input[name=is_recur_radio][id=CIVICRM_QFID_is_recur_radio]').change(function(){
if ($("input[name=is_recur_radio]:checked").attr("id")=="CIVICRM_QFID_is_recur_radio") {
    $('input[name=payment_processor_id][value=5]').prop("disabled", true);
    }
  });


$('input[name=is_recur_radio][value=month]').change(function(){
if ($("input[name=is_recur_radio]:checked").attr("value")=="CIVICRM_QFID_month_is_recur_radio") {
    $('input[name=payment_processor_id][value=5]').prop("disabled", false);
    }  
});
```

Comment: Do you have any relevant HTML to show us?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I can provide the URL of actual page, if that helps @DavidsaysreinstateMonica Thanks

Comment: No, don't link to the page - because once you fix the problem, or reorganise your site - the problem disappears and our help is useless to future visitors. Instead produce a "*[mcve]*" to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Thanks @DavidsaysreinstateMonica Added HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your both radio name i.e : `monthly and single` are same you can simply use only one `change` event handler and change value depending on condition.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('input[name=is_recur_radio]').change(function() {
  //check for id and add or remove disabled
  $("input[name=is_recur_radio]:checked").attr("id") == "CIVICRM_QFID_is_recur_radio" ? $('input[name=payment_processor_id][value=5]').prop("disabled", true) : $('input[name=payment_processor_id][value=5]').prop("disabled", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input class="crm-form-radio" value type="radio" id="CIVICRM_QFID_is_recur_radio" name="is_recur_radio">
  <label for="CIVICRM_QFID_is_recur_radio">Single</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input class="crm-form-radio" value="month" type="radio" id="CIVICRM_QFID_month_is_recur_radio" name="is_recur_radio">
  <label for="CIVICRM_QFID_month_is_recur_radio">Month</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input class="payment_processor_gocardless crm-form-radio" value="5" type="radio" id="CIVICRM_QFID_5_payment_processor_id" name="payment_processor_id">
  <label for="CIVICRM_QFID_5_payment_processor_id">Payment</label>

</div>
```

Comment: how can i clear the Payment radio when I switch from Monthly to Single if Payment was already selected? Thanks

Comment: Hi try like this `$('input[name=payment_processor_id][value=5]').removeAttr('checked')`